# how to implement google chat in iphone app

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xmpp, xmppframework

i have searched a lot on the web but can not find the actual sample source code that can help me to get started for google chat implementation , the sample code provided with the xmpp framework also does not tell clearly about it, as it have a sample project of Mac desktop application.

I have been able to show all my friends who are online/ofline/away with the help of sample project(iphoneXmpp) which is provided in the xmppframework, but it also doest tell anything about how to initiate a chat.

Please provide me any sample source code so that i can initialize the google chat in my app.

i am really stuck.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okey i didnt give up and had some solution after looking into the desktop application of xmpp framework and tried to include it in my iphone app..

here is the code to send message to our chat friend on gmail..

```
-(void)sendMessage
{
messageStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[msgField text] ];
//messageStr = [NSString stringWithString:@"hello ji....."];

BOOL isEmpty = [ self validateIsEmpty:msgField.text];
if([messageStr length] > 0 && isEmpty == NO )
{
    NSXMLElementK *body = [NSXMLElementK elementWithName:@"body"];
    [body setStringValue:messageStr];

    NSXMLElementK *message = [NSXMLElementK elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[[user jid] full]];
    [message addChild:body];
            [[self xmppStream ] sendElement:message];
}
```

and in didReceiveMessage , i have following code...

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{

NSLog(@"---------- xmppStream:didReceiveMessage: ----------");

NSLog(@"--jid---%@", [[user jid] full]);
NSLog(@"--from----%@", [message from]);
//if(![[[user jid] full] isEqual:[message from]]) return;// important when chatting with 2 or more .. and receiving 2 or more messages...

if([message isChatMessageWithBody])
{
    NSString *msg = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];

    NSLog(@"mmmmmmmmmmssssssgggg-%@",msg);

    [str appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@\n\n", [message from], msg]];
    [chatBox setText:str];
}
}
```

i'm able to send/recieve the chat using these two methods but problem is that some times the person's id which i selected from the table view of available online contacts(to whom we can chat with) does'nt receive the message but any other person receives the message..

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message {

    NSString *msg = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
    NSString *from = [[message attributeForName:@"from"] stringValue];

    if (msg.length==0) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Receiving Message" 
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"From %@",from]  
                                                           delegate:nil 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];


    }

    if (msg.length!=0) {
        NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [m setObject:msg forKey:@"msg"];
        [m setObject:from forKey:@"sender"];

        NSLog(@"message received : %@", m);
        [_messageDelegate newMessageReceived:m];
    }
}
```

This works great for you, and it will also give you the alert who is sending the message and who wants to chat with you, However I'm just stuck from where should I implement the Logout for the user through which I logged in to iOS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial should do the trick : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/