# sending message and recieving message in iphone app using xmpp framework

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, chat, xmppframework

Hi I am successfully adding xmpp framework for my iPhone app after that if i am sending message or receiving message what is the steps,
i search in Google but it shows how to integrate xmpp framework not how to use xmpp framework
is there any tutorial for sending or receiving  using xmpp framework
can any body help me on this.

Comment: If your using this: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework I would look at the examples and study them.

Comment: @kdogisthebest sry i dint see any tutorials in tht link saying hw to implement chat...Can you point out please ...??Help needed

Comment: [**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325743/how-to-implement-google-chat-in-iphone-app**][1]

I think above link can help us.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325743/how-to-implement-google-chat-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 1):

If u want to send a message, there u should convert ur message and u have to create a DXMLElement ( XmppMessage ), and while receiving a message , you have to convert the DXMLElement (XmppMessage )  to a message.

For sending message, you have to use the Xmpp Delegate function:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didSendMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message;
```

For receiving message, you have to use the Xmpp Delegate function:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message;
```

do u need anyother help, i will help u .. :)

Comment: Hi Rahul i am integrating xmpp framework successfully but problem is when app enters in background i am unable to handle local notification please help me on this

Comment: what is the problem there in local notification. give me some description abt ur problem..